# Is there any file-based db with concurrent per-file user access similar to MS Access but Open Source?

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access, open-source

Most time I build simple applications that share data through an MS Access DB through a network drive.

However, MS Access in damn slow, does not support common features of SQL, is a pain to automate and makes uses to "explore" my application's data directly.

I would like to migrate to an different db with a similar profile. It should be

- needing no installation, because they are not permitted through the IT departement
- be file-based (same as above)
- savely placeable on a network drive to give multi-user support
- open source
- (preferably have a pure java driver)

Do you know anything out there that matches at least some of my creterias?

I have reviewed sqlite, derby, hsqldb. They all seem to support all requirements except the shareability through an network drive.

But this is the most required feature.

I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: I hate to not answer the question but you really need to beat the IT department into letting you install a proper database, even a free one such as mysql or SQL Server Express. You'll hopefully get an answer for a file-based system for now but I can't see it scaling well.

Comment: Most of my programs are really small. They get input on regular basis and have to give editing capabilities with rights management and validations to the users. Additionally they should create small reports, so there is no real need for scale. We mostly try out new things. If it works good, we hand it to the IT department. Then it's their problem ;)

Comment: @Marcus - Is it not the case that the company has a standard database format used for other purposes besides your application? I would think the IT department would desire uniformity wrt to databases rather than compelling each developer to whip up their own.

Comment: Any file-based database will be slow, and may have problems, on a network drive. I guess you're stuck with building a business case for the IT department to allow you to install a proper DB, or use an existing one.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on the slow part.   There are some tricks when it comes to multi user performance.   See my Access Performance FAQ page at http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm

Comment: I would vote for using something else, since the "slow" problem indicates that whoever is using Access/Jet/ACE doesn't really know what they are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the requirement "needing no installation" is a show-stopper for you. The alternative is to learn to make better use of Access. With careful design, it *will* surprise you. In the olden days, when lawyers in the US were expected to design, build, and maintain their own litigation support databases, I used to demonstrate design and queries against a 2,000,000 row Access database. Response times were less than 250 msec. I know that sounds awfully slow nowadays, but back then--early 1990s--that was ripping fast.

Not kidding about the lawyers. The [canonical reference for litigation support databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471509140) at the time was *Wilmer, Cutler, and Pickering Manual on Litigation Support Databases*. In my experience, most lawyers believe their expertise at the bar transfers to all other fields. Including database design.

Comment: I think I will have to try this. But I'm impressed of your query times. My queries will have many subsequent clauses and will involve views. I believe MS Access goes down then anyway. I don't know this domain, but maybe this was no query involving relations?

Comment: No, join performance was fine. The first time I used Access professionally, I built a prototype to test against another desktop dbms. (R:Base? Not sure. Access 1.0 cost $99 then. It was our cheapest alternative.) I think the SQL statement that was killing them took 10 pages to print, 33 hours to run, then printed 15,000 pages.  (Insurance industry requirement.) In Access, I was able to implement some of the subqueries as views, and join on the views. (We tried that in the old system, but it didn't help performance.) First run finished in 13 minutes. (Not a typo.)

Comment: If you have slow queries, you should Google "Jet SHOWPLAN" and follow the instructions there. It will tell you what the Jet query optimizer is doing with your SQL (though it doesn't show the optimization for subqueries -- you'd need to test those separately). There is nothing you've said that de facto indicates slowness, unless you're trying to run the thing across a slow or unreliable network connection (e.g., across a WAN).

Answer (score 1):

Try [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

From their homepage:

> It offers a small, fast multithreaded and transactional database engine which offers in-memory and disk-based tables and supports embedded and server modes.

It's also used by JBoss AS as its internal database.

> I have reviewed sqlite, derby, hsqldb. They all seem to support all requirements except the shareability through an network drive.

You might need to put a small server on the network, though :)

Comment: I can't set up a server. That would involve the IT departement again and I'm in a very early stage of developement. The application still needs evaluation. However, it's shall go productive as soon as possible and coding is finished using a local MySQL server. Now the question is how to deploy with no installation and without true client/server?

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with Firebird Embedded with great results, the only problem: no multi-user access is posible.

- It provides you with full modern RDBMS features.
- No need for installation: just copy a dll.
- The database is a single file.

Here is some info: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html